# Ordering a table by another sub-table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables which are connected via a one-to-many relationship (One record in table A will have multiple records in Table B which are connected to it). For reference, Table A is holds Incident Records, while Table B holds notes added for progress on the incidents in Table A.

The Tables:

TableA:

```
SELECT [IncID]
      ,[TechId]
      ,[TechName]
      ,[Complete]
      ,[StartDateTime]
      ,[CompleteDateTime]
      ,[Subject]
      ,[Description]
      ,[Resolution]
  FROM [TableA]
```

Table B:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [IncHistID]
      ,[IncID]
      ,[TechID]
      ,[TechName]
      ,[NoteDate]
      ,[NoteTime]
      ,[Description]
      ,[ContactName]
      ,[RowNum]
  FROM [TableB]
```

The Two tables are connected via the [IncID] Column. I want to be able to order TableA by TableB's NoteDate Column.

I have gotten TableB in the desired order using the below Query:

```
SELECT [IncID]
        ,Max(Notedate) as NoteDate
  FROM [PDSupport].[dbo].[vwWebIncidentsHist3]
  Group by IncID
  Order By  Notedate Desc
```

Comment: use a join then order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have indexes on IncID in both tables, using a join and then simply ordering seems to be the most efficient and standard approach...

```
SELECT A.[IncID]
  ,A.[TechId]
  ,A.[TechName]
  ,A.[Complete]
  ,A.[StartDateTime]
  ,A.[CompleteDateTime]
  ,A.[Subject]
  ,A.[Description]
  ,A.[Resolution]
  ,max(B.noteDate) mNotedate
FROM tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B
 on A.IncID=B.IncID
GROUP BY A.[IncID]
  ,A.[TechId]
  ,A.[TechName]
  ,A.[Complete]
  ,A.[StartDateTime]
  ,A.[CompleteDateTime]
  ,A.[Subject]
  ,A.[Description]
  ,A.[Resolution]
ORDER BY mNoteDate desc
```